# Double Join in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these three tables as below

office.rb

```
has_many :documents
has_one :information
```

information.rb

```
belongs_to :office
```

document.rb

```
belongs_to :office
```

I am trying to write a query where as below

documents_controller.rb

```
def search
 @documents = Document.all
 @documents.joins(:office).where("offices.name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") OR @documents.joins(:office).joins(:information).where("informations.first_name ILIKE ? OR informations.last_name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
end
```

I am trying to achieve the above statement but I am doing something wrong. Please help me fix this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the idea is to retrieve any document where the office's name is the search term or where the information first/last name is the search term, right?

The first step is to create the joins:

```rb
Document.joins(office: :information)
```

The second step is to create the condition:

```rb
where("offices.name ILIKE :term OR informations.first_name ILIKE :term OR informations.last_name ILIKE :term", term: "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

and joining both sentences:

```rb
Document.joins(office: :information).where("offices.name ILIKE :term OR informations.first_name ILIKE :term OR informations.last_name ILIKE :term", term: "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

there are other fancy ways to do the same thing like using `or` scope but probably will be more complex to understand:

```rb
search_term = "%#{params[:search]}%"
base_query = Document.joins(office: :information)
office_scope = base_query.where("offices.name ILIKE :term", search_term)
first_name_scope = base_query.where("informations.first_name ILIKE :term", search_term)
last_name_scope = base_query.where("informations.last_name ILIKE :term", search_term)
office_scope.or(first_name_scope).or(last_name_scope)
```